# Returning most recent value from a row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I finished standardizing over 100,000 entries from national time-series data in a research project but there's one last step: many countries do not report data for every year. I want to fill those gaps with the entry from the most recent year.

Each row of each sheet represents one country from 1995 to 2015, left to right. Everything will be migrated to a new worksheet. Is there a way to carry the most recent value? This must be done without VBA for technical reasons.

Comment: Here's an example: Lithuania 67 (1995), blank (1996), blank (1997), blank (1998), 73 (1999), blank (2000), 73 (2001), 74 (2002)...

Comment: Yes, copy the datatable shell(headers, formatting etc), and use a formula to fill in the values in the new table. For example, if the original datapoint is in A2: each new datapoint would be a formula like =IF(A2="", OFFSET(A2, 0, -1), A2)

Comment: In case you are not aware, if you bring up the "Select Data Source" dialog, and click "Hidden and Empty Cells", then you can choose to "Connect data points with line". This is slightly less misleading than some arbitrary, or repeated, value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal if function to get the output[image]

Green colored cell shows the desired output